# Skype For Business formats PromptDialog weird

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, skype-for-business

When a user asks our bot a question and the language processor doesn't have confidence we return a set of options in a PromptDialog. In the bot framework debugger the data comes back with nicely sorted, clickable cards. In Skype it comes back looking like this.

---

Did you mean: Options:

- 1. Option one.
- 1. Option two.
- 1. Option three.

...

---

So, we build the Prompt like this:

```
var questions = ["1. Option one.", "2. Option two.", "3. Option three."];        
var options = new PromptOptions<string>(
    prompt: Resource.answerSelectionPrompt, //"Did you mean:"
    tooManyAttempts: Resource.tooManyAttempts, //"Sorry! not able to match any of the options"
    options: questions,
    attempts: 0);
PromptDialog.Choice(context: context, resume: ResumeCallback, promptOptions: options);
```

How do I get Skype to behave like a civilized channel? Specifically I don't want it resetting my numbered list - I'd like the users to be able to reply with "1", "2", or "3". Also, I'm not sure why it feels like adding the word `Options:` to the prompt. No one asked it to do that, and I wish it'd stop.

Comment: I've prepended "Option 1:", "Option 2:", ...etc to the values of questions. that fixes the forced formatting, but it's less than ideal. It also still sneaks the word 'Options' in there. There must be a way to get skype to trust my formatting.